# State saved, but saying its not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app similar to the default ReactJS tutorial.

I have a function in a component called after a form is submitted that looks like:

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    name: "First Product",
    showOwner: true
  }
},

handleFormSubmit: function (name) {
  console.log(name); //Returns "Hello world"
  console.log(this.state.name); // Returns "First Product"

  this.setState({name: name});
  this.setState({showOwner: false});

  console.log(this.state.name); // Returns "First Product" still
}
```

For some reason, when I check it out in React developer tools, it shows that this.state.name **IS** being set to the new value, but when I console.log like shown it still shows the first value instead of "Hello World"?

Comment: Accidentally missed closing quotes on line 3? Can you should us how you call `handleFormSubmit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html :

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. **Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.**
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Also:

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

So, following the documentation, you would want this from your code:

```
handleFormSubmit: function (name) {
  console.log(name); //Returns "Hello world"
  console.log(this.state.name); // Returns "First Product"

  this.setState({
    name: name,
    showOwner: false
  }, function() {
    // Should return "Hello world" after the state has been set.
    console.log(this.state.name);
  }.bind(this));

  // Returns "First Product" still, since setState is not synchronous
  console.log(this.state.name);
}
```

I don't know react, but that's what the docs say and I have no reason to believe that wouldn't work.